# 4 Image Controls in a Composite Control, Not showing action buttons

Tags: sitecore-client, custom-field

I have created a composite control in Sitecore 9 and I can use that in template editor when adding new fields.

[image]

This control is supposed to show an Image control where I can browse and select images but I can't see any browse button.

[image]

Out of the box image control shows these options

[image]

my code

```
public class CustomImage : Sitecore.Web.UI.HtmlControls.Control
{
    public CustomImage()
    {
        this.Class = "scContentControl";
        base.Activation = true;
    }
    protected override void OnLoad(EventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnLoad(e);
        if (!Sitecore.Context.ClientPage.IsEvent)
        {
            var image = new Sitecore.Shell.Applications.ContentEditor.Image();
            this.Controls.Add(image);

        }
        else
        {
        }
    }
}
```

I could not find any example on how to add image control in composite control, so code is very basic.

Once I get this working, my goal is to have 4 image controls in one composite control.